# Не верная сортировка DESC из БД

Tags: php, sql

подскажите почему при сортировке DESC из БД, выдаёт не правильную последовательность

```
SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Выдаёт

```
2019-11-16
2019-11-03
2019-10-28
2019-09-02
2018-09-29
```

Comment: Да всё нормально, что не нравится-то?

Comment: перепробовал кучу функций - всё бестолку...хочу, чтобы так получилось
2019-11-03
2019-11-16
2019-10-28
2018-09-29
2019-09-02

Comment: Это с какого перепугу 2018-й год должен затесаться между двумя по 2019?

Comment: там тоже 2019...поспешил

Comment: Поправьте у себя исходные данные - и тогда попробуйте. Сортировка получится какая нужно.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под "исходными данными"?

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5f5c274b5cea0265c04a235c75ae1f1)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам видится ошибка из-за того, что вы смотрите только на месяц и число, и кажется, что последние два элемента не в том порядке. А там — другой год.

Comment: перепробовал кучу функций - всё бестолку...хочу, чтобы так получилось
2019-11-03
2019-11-16
2019-10-28
2019-09-29
2019-09-02

Comment: Вы перечисляете дату "2019-09-29", которой нет в списке — в вопросе у одной из дат 2018 год, а не 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Команда DESC используется для сортировки данных, возвращаемых в порядке убывания.

Comment: DESC не команда, а параметр. Изначально - параметр выражения в предложении ORDER BY, но расширения могут вводить такой параметр и выражениям в других предложениях (например, в GROUP BY).